# How to scale image with same quality using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having sequence of images in HTML. All are large size images, I am scaling theme in initial display and on click all enlarge.

So the issue is, when image is scaled down, it shows pixelated output. ([See link](http://jsfiddle.net/parag1111/K9Q57/))

If anyone have solution to have consistent output when image is scaled, please give suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to scale them not dynamically in the browser. Create thumbnails on serverside by using libs like imagick or gd.

Answer (score 1):

The quality of an image scaled down by the browser will depend on the image scaler used by the browser. Most of these have no method of resampling, and simply remove pixels from the image to reduce its size - hence the pixellated look.

There is nothing you can do about this, other than to use separate images for the small and large versions.

Comment: Can this help anyway? http://filamentgroup.com/examples/responsive-images-new/demos/A-Default/demo.html

Comment: @ParagGajjar That is using two images as well - it's just switching between them depending on the size of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

As floating concept is there the resolution varies differently in system.So its better to use good quality image.

Check this link  http://codecanyon.net/item/imageresize/59935

If it is useful for you tell me I can send you the code.

Comment: Thanks, but images will be fixed so no need of this script.