# Jquery responsive image resizing method that maintains the quality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I have a background image which is responsive. It adapts to the container with the background-size: 100% method which keeps the aspect ratio. However, for older browsers like Firefox 18 and below and all versions of internet explorer I get a bad image when scaled (jagged or blurry). I tried the css bicubic interpolation (internet explorer) and "image-rendering" (firefox) fix yet no effect what can be observed.

My question is: is there a jquery or javascript way that does the same job while preserving the quality? Like a browser independent scaling method. Googled but found nothing.

I know this is not ideal in terms of speed and I should instead do the resizing in my image editing software but this is not an option in my scenario.

Would be happy to hear about your answers,

Sincerely,

Michael

Comment: show u your css, html and js code

Comment: [Kind of related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358943/how-to-scale-image-with-same-quality-using-jquery). Basically standard scaling (not with background-size) will simply lose a lot of pixels. Crazy idea - maybe you could use smaller image and stretch it?

Comment: Hello VDesign, there is nothing special to show...just a standard css class with a background image with background-size: 100%.

Comment: I know what he's talking about, if you use a large high quality picture and scale it down (enough) on your webpage, in IE it's jagged as hell. In Chrome all is good. It's just stupid-browser-syndrome

Comment: @myfunkyside I found a solution. For internet explorer 9 to 11+ use javascript media queries for targeting them using media query hacks such as  media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) ... If the media query matches use document.write to load an SVG inline image. Inline because svg backgrounds look really bad in ie.

Comment: @myfunkside updated my answer. check it out now :D

Comment: @myfunkyside http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#quick-start

add the img within the brackets match : function() {IMG with document load},

Make sure you add the code where you want the image to be.

Answer (score 1):

The only good solution I found to provide the best possible quality is by using a css responsive method.

For latest chrome & safari you have the new HTML attribute SRCSET.
For olders browsers, you can use your images as a div background and change it dynamically with CSS only.

For very old browsers, the only way is to grab images with different sizes using JS...

Comment: There must be a javascript / jquery equivalent to the css responsive method for older browsers. I can imagine that jquery could, independent from the browsers rendering, scale down an image without loss like chrome, safari, firefox and opera.

Comment: Yes, there are advanced methods (with Canvas API per exemple). But it will be very slower, I think the best is just to have multiple images sizes.

Comment: Indeed but my website works on a simple 240px up to 8K Ultra High Definition screens. So I need to scale down. I added main breakpoints but I want the rest to be scaled by the browser. I also want things to look good when the user changes the window size. Have a look at this: http://responsiveimg.com/

Comment: This plugin is interesting, but the images are generated by php on the fly and it may be slower than pre-generated images. You way to make big breakpoints and then rescale a bit to adapt is the good way, scaling is working good if it's just a bit. Don't forget to use CSS for quality if it's blurry (I had a little hack one time with translateZ(0) and outline:0, don't know if it's still working)

Comment: My breakpoints happen like every 1000px. So thats like 10 times the same image at different sizes. The plugin would then generate new images independent from the browser so that there is no horrible quality loss. The question is how to target the older browsers and IE only. Modernizr wont do the job here so im left with browser sniffing for Firefox 18 below and IE 11 and below.

Comment: @FC': don't spend your time to these two. They are answering and accepting each others questions.